# Automating Spot Instance Replacement that is about to be terminated with a new Spot Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

As we know, when a spot instance is about to be terminated , we get notified 2 minutes in advance.Now i want my services to be running by replacing the spot  instance that is notified to be deleted, by a new spot instance.
Are there any existing ways to automatically replace an EC2 spot instance by a new spot instance?.

Answer (score 0):

From [Spot Fleet - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html):

> A Spot Fleet is a set of Spot Instances and optionally On-Demand Instances that is launched based on criteria that you specify. The Spot Fleet selects the Spot capacity pools that meet your needs and launches Spot Instances to meet the target capacity for the fleet. By default, **Spot Fleets are set to maintain target capacity by launching replacement instances after Spot Instances in the fleet are terminated**. You can submit a Spot Fleet as a one-time request, which does not persist after the instances have been terminated. You can include On-Demand Instance requests in a Spot Fleet request.